# Как добраться до View элементов после инициализации?

Tags: java, android

Уже второй день не могу сделать, чтобы сегодняшний день подсвечивался определенным цветом. Как добраться до `View` компонента из `GridView` после инициализации адаптера и построения `GridView`?

**CalendarView**

```
public class CalendarView extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

    private GridView                        mGrid;
    private View                            mConvertView;
    private GregorianCalendar               mCalendar;
    private Date[]                          mWeek;
    private Context                         mContext;
    private TextView                        mMonthText;
    private SimpleDateFormat                mFormatMonth;
    private SimpleDateFormat                mFormatDay;
    private SimpleDateFormat                mFormatYear;
    private OnDispatchDateSelectListener    mListenerDateSelect;
    private Button                          mArrowRight;
    private Button                          mArrowLeft;
    private CalendarAdapter                 mAdapter;
    public interface OnDispatchDateSelectListener {
        public void onDispatchDateSelect(Date date);
    }
    public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext            = context;
        mFormatMonth        = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        mFormatDay          = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
        mFormatYear         = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

        mConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.calendar, this);
        mGrid=(GridView)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_days);

        mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mMonthText=(TextView)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month);
        mArrowLeft=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calendar_arrow_left);
        mArrowLeft.setOnClickListener(this);

        mArrowRight=(Button)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_arrow_right);
        mArrowRight.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCalendar = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.setTime(new Date());
        mCalendar.getInstance().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

        Integer dayDifference = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1 ? -6 : (Calendar.MONDAY - mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayDifference);


        mWeek=new Date[7];
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            mWeek[i]=mCalendar.getTime();
            mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }

        mAdapter=new CalendarAdapter(mContext, mWeek);

        mGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

**CalendarAdapter**

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context             mContext;
    private Date[]              mWeek;
    private SimpleDateFormat    mFormatNumber;
    private SimpleDateFormat    mFormatDay;
    private LayoutInflater      mInflater;



    public CalendarAdapter(Context _context, Date[] _week) {
            mContext        = _context;
            mWeek           = _week;
            mFormatNumber   = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
            mFormatDay      = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            mInflater       = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }


    //походу хранит в себе поля для ввода.
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView     tvDay;
        public TextView     tvNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWeek.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mWeek[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    //Здесь происходит формирование листа.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        //если неделя заполняется первый раз выполняется
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView     = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day, null);
            holder          = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvDay    = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_day);
            holder.tvNumber = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvDay.setText(mFormatDay.format(mWeek[position]));
        holder.tvNumber.setText(mFormatNumber.format(mWeek[position]));


        return convertView;
    }



}
```

Comment: А зачем после? Во время инициализации и подсвечивайте. В методе `getView()` например

Answer (score 1):

А в чём проблема реализовать это в Адаптере?
В методе **public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)**
вы получаете свой View компонент, там вы присваиваете значения своим элементам, вот там и можно делать проверку на "Сегодняшнее число" и подсветить нужный